# reverse perspective projection

Tags: math, opengl, 3d, picking, reverseprojection

I'm using

```
worldview_inverse * (projection_inverse * vector)
```

to transform screen space coordinates into world space coordinates.
I assumed that

```
(x,y,1,1)
```

would transform to a point on the far plane, while

```
(x,y,-1,1)
```

transforms to a point on the near plane, and connecting the line I can query all objects in the view frustum that intersect the line.
After the transformation I divide the resulting points by their respective .w component.
This works for the far-plane, but the point on the near plane somehow gets transformed to the world space origin.

I think this has to do with the w components of 1 I'm feeding into the inverse projection, because usually it is 1 before projection, not after, and I'm doing the reverse projection. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I think you need some more sample code.  Especially the part that is setting your near point to the origin

Comment: Also, could you provide the projection matrix you are using? Is it offset?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I know this is only a workaround, but you can deduce the near plane point by only using the far point and the viewing position.

```
near_point = view_position
           + (far_point - view_position) * (near_distance / far_distance)
```

As for you real problem. First, don't forget to divide by W! Also, depending on your projection matrix, have you tried (x,y,0,1) as opposed to z=-1.

```
near_point = worldview_inverse * (projection_inverse * vector)
near_point /= near_point.W
```

Comment: yes, I considered this, but now I'm interested in the math side of the original problem ;)

Comment: Hehe, yeah sorry about that. I updated my answer to try to tackle your real problem.